# The wave function of the photon and electron are probability waves, does this mean the Maxwell are some time correct some time wrong?

Tags: energy-conservation, schroedinger-equation, maxwell-equations, quantum-interpretations, wave-particle-duality

The wave is probability wave, it is seams that the wave function some time is correct, the energy is sent out. Some time it is wrong the energy is not sent out.

Hence we can obtained the conclusion that Maxwell equations and   Schrödinger's equation some time is correct and some time is wrong. The theory of Maxwell equations and   Schrödinger's are partially correct.

Is this conclusion correct?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow why QM & E&M are "partially correct" or "sometime[s] wrong" given (probability) waves.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is the wrong conclusion. Classical equations and laws emerge from the quantum mechanical ones in a mathematically consistent way, similar to how thermodynamics, which has its special mathematics framework,emerges from statistical mechanics.

Photons built up the classical electromagnetic wave in a superposition of their q[uantum mechanical wavefunctions](https://arxiv.org/ftp/quant-ph/papers/0604/0604169.pdf) and this can [be proven within quantum field  theory.](https://motls.blogspot.gr/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html)

In general, the underlying level is quantum mechanical , and the classical emerges from this level.

There is nothing wrong with an operator interpretation of the equations of quantum mechanics , which as far as the probabilities are concerned , are quite deterministic. The indeterminacy in the classical variables for positioning particles does not make anything wrong, because the indeterminacy is for very small values, comensurate to the Planck constant h. The variables in the classical range  obey the [Heisenberg uncertainty](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/uncer.html) so there is no contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting references! What about the frequent claim that the electromagnetic field is *not* the quantum mechanical wave function of the photon?

Comment: It is correct. The wavefunction of the photon is the quantum mechanical solution, where the differentials in the maxwell equations are used as quantum mechanical operators. The  classical EM field is the simple solution, but also,as I said,in QED it can be shown that the wavefunctions of the photon ( complex numbers) build up the classical field (real E and B fields)

Comment: Thank you Anna! I will also read the paper you referenced.